# test="" on a boolean always returns true

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, boolean

Why does

```
<xsl:if test="<XPATH to boolean value here>">
...
</xsl:if>
```

ALWAYS return true?

Since boolean can be 0,1,"false" and "true" by definition, the ONLY way to test for a boolean value is to do string comparison against these. This can't be right.

Comment: can you please post your current XPath expression with an XML fragment?

Comment: This is not a question at all. Please, give a specific example -- what is exactly the XPath expression and what is the XML file (the simplest possible, please) on which this XPath expression is evaluated?

Comment: Prefer to see an example, I guess there is a minor mistake in the syntax.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `test` specified in `<xsl:if>` works as if it called the `boolean` function.  This function doesn't work the way you might think.  If its argument evaluates to a node-set (which it will be if you use a path as its argument) it will return true if the node-set is not empty, and false otherwise.  So effectively, you're testing for the existence of an element, not its value.  If `foo` contains `false`,

```
<xsl:if test="/path/to/foo">
```

will always evaluate to true, since what you're really asking in that test is "does this element exist?" and not "is element's value true?"  And the element exists.

The rule that boolean values must be `true`, `false`, `1`, or `0` is a part of XML Schema ([which see](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean)) and not XPath, which doesn't know anything about this rule.  (XPath 1.0, that is.  XPath 2.0/XQuery 1.0 has [the `fn:boolean` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-boolean), which does smart, i.e. XML Schema aware, evaluation of boolean values.)  To determine if a value is true in XSLT, you have to explicitly check it:

```
<xsl:if test="/path/to/foo = 'true' or /path/to/foo = '1'">
```

Comment: If I'm reading http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-Boolean-Functions correctly, there should be no difference between the two tests. Actually xsl:if is specified to convert the test result as if by a call to the boolean function.

Comment: You know, I knew that.  Corrected.

Comment: In your example above, you will run into a problem once you use a schema-aware processor. Since the processor knows from the schema that /path/to/foo is xs:boolean, it will produce an error message "Cannot compare xs:boolean to xs:string". I have exactly this problem (with a boolean attribute) - and I don't really know how to solve it. Any help?

Comment: The only schema-aware XSLT processors I know of are XSLT 2.0 processors, and they support the `fn:boolean` function.  But I don't have any direct experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a whole bunch of ideas here:

[Empty Element](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N3328.html)

[how to test an empty element in XSL?](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/87185-how-test-empty-element-xsl)

Answer (score 0):

The xpath specification give a boolean function.  Thus boolean(Value) will always return true or false.